# Javascript code for "save as template" in Thunderbird?

Tags: xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm trying to create my own custom buttons in Thunderbird. I am trying to make a "Save as Template" stand-alone button. I've gotten the chrome directory completed but I cannot figure out what the command is in the button.js file. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate the command "cmd_saveAsTemplate" with your toolbar button.

For tasks like this one, I recommoned [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) which lets you dive into the a window's XUL structure.